# Docker OpenGL support without GPU, gl error: linking with uncompiled/unspecialized shader

Tags: docker, ubuntu, opengl, dockerfile, nvidia

In order to build up a headless simulation cluster, we're working on containerization of our existing tools. Right now, the accessible server does not have any NVIDIA GPUs.

One problem, that we encounter is, that a specific application uses OpenGL for rendering. With an physical GPU, the simulation tool is running without any problem. To ship around the GPU dependencies, we're using Mesa 3D OpenGL Software Rendering (Gallium), LLVMpipe, and OpenSWR Drivers. For reference, we had a look at https://github.com/jamesbrink/docker-opengl.

The current Dockerfile, which builds mesa 19.0.2 (using gcc-8) from source, looks like this:

```
# OPENGL SUPPORT ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# start with plain ubuntu as base image for testing
FROM ubuntu AS builder

# install some needed packages and set gcc-8 as default compiler
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    llvm-7 \
    llvm-dev \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    bison \
    flex \
    gettext \
    libtool \
    python-dev\
    git \
    pkgconf \
    python-mako \
    zlib1g-dev \
    x11proto-gl-dev \
    libxext-dev \
    xcb \
    libx11-xcb-dev \
    libxcb-dri2-0-dev \
    libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
    libdrm-dev \
    g++ \
    make \
    xvfb \
    x11vnc \
    g++-8 && \
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 800 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8

# get mesa (using 19.0.2 as later versions dont use the configure script)
WORKDIR /mesa
RUN git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa.git
WORKDIR /mesa/mesa
RUN git checkout mesa-19.0.2
#RUN git checkout mesa-18.2.2

# build and install mesa
RUN libtoolize && \
    autoreconf --install && \
    ./configure \
        --enable-glx=gallium-xlib \
        --with-gallium-drivers=swrast,swr \
        --disable-dri \
        --disable-gbm \
        --disable-egl \
        --enable-gallium-osmesa \
        --enable-autotools \
        --enable-llvm \
        --with-llvm-prefix=/usr/lib/llvm-7/ \
        --prefix=/usr/local && \
    make -j 4 && \
    make install && \
    rm -rf /mesa



# SIM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM ubuntu
COPY --from=builder /usr/local /usr/local

# copy all simulation binaries to the image
COPY .....

# update ubuntu and install all sim dependencies
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        xterm \
        freeglut3 \
        openssh-server \
        synaptic \
        nfs-common \
        mesa-utils \
        xfonts-75dpi \
        libusb-0.1-4 \
        python \
        libglu1-mesa \
        libqtgui4 \
        gedit \
        xvfb \
        x11vnc \
        llvm-7-dev \
        expat \
        nano && \
    dpkg -i /vtdDeb/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

# set the environment variables (display -> 99 and LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE)
ENV DISPLAY=":99" \
    GALLIUM_DRIVER="llvmpipe" \
    LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE="1" \
    LP_DEBUG="" \
    LP_NO_RAST="false" \
    LP_NUM_THREADS="" \
    LP_PERF="" \
    MESA_VERSION="19.0.2" \
    XVFB_WHD="1920x1080x24"
```

If we now start the container and initialize the xvfb session, all glx examples like glxgears are working. Also the output of `glxinfo | grep '^direct rendering:'` is yes, so OpenGL is working.

However, if we start our simulation binary (which is provided from some company and cannot be changed now), following error messages are provided:

```
uniform block ub_lights has no binding.
uniform block ub_lights has no binding.
FRAGMENT glCompileShader "../data/Shaders/roadRendererFrag.glsl" FAILED
FRAGMENT Shader "../data/Shaders/roadRendererFrag.glsl" infolog:
0:277(48): error: unsized array index must be constant
0:344(48): error: unsized array index must be constant

glLinkProgram "RoadRenderingBase_Program" FAILED
Program "RoadRenderingBase_Program" infolog:
error: linking with uncompiled/unspecialized shader
```

Any idea how to fix that? For us, the error message is kind of vacuous.
Did someone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Edit in the failing shaders.  You can use the [`MESA_GLSL=dump` or `MESA_GLSL=log`](https://www.mesa3d.org/shading.html#envvars) envvar to capture them.